# Get last 30 seconds of HLS stream with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a live HLS stream which has not yet ended. I am trying to extract the last 30 seconds (now minus 30 seconds clip)

I tried

ffmpeg -sseof -30 -i audio.m3u8 -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4

but this does not work since the audio clip has not ended. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`segment` muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) like this:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.m3u8 -acodec copy -vcodec copy \
       -f segment -segment_wrap 2 -segment_time 40 \
       out_%d.mp4')
```

This creates `out_0.mp4` and `out_1.mp4`, each roughly 40 seconds long. As the option name suggests, the output number gets wrapped by `segment_wrap` option and overwrites the previous output. So, in the end, you should have 1 40-second long segment and another <40 seconds long. Run ffmpeg one more time to join the 2 files in the right order and grab the last 30 seconds.

disclaimer: I've only tested with a wav file. Hopefully it behaves the same way with your mp4 copy operation.